# Enter single cell value in pandas dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame(df) as following,

```
 A | B
--------
a1 |
a2 |*
a3 |
```

a1,a2,a3 are strings. I need to enter a value to column B, row a2 location(*). How can I do this using labels only?

I tried

```
df[df['A']=='a2']['B']='new_value'
```

It did not update the value as expected.

Comment: `df.loc[df['A']=='a2', 'B'] = 'new_value'`

Comment: Use the loc accesor together with Boolean indexing.   `df.loc[df['B']=='*','B']='newvalue'`